# Log only slow queries mongodb

Tags: mongodb

I'm trying to log only the slow queries(which take more than 10 sec to execute) in the mongodb log files.

I'm running the mongo as

```
mongod --fork --quiet -v --logpath /home/logs/mongod.log --logRotate reopen --logappend
```

and set the profiling as

```
db.setProfilingLevel(1, 10000)
```

but when tail the log file, it print all the query. I could see a lot of queries and it run time as 0ms. Is there anything else I need to add to get only the slow queries?

Comment: Did you read a documentation https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/manage-the-database-profiler/#view-profiler-data ?

Comment: @Neodan Thanks. As per the document, I could view the explain info of the slow queries using db.system.profile.find().limit(10).sort( { ts : -1 } ).pretty(). I would like to know, is it possible to reduce the log file size by logging only slow queries.

Answer (score 1):

There are couple of options to log only slow calls that take more than specified threshold on mongodb:

1. Pass these configs on mongod.conf: [Check these params](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/#operationProfiling.slowOpThresholdMs)
2. Start mongod with these params in command line:

   a. `--profile` (0=off 1=slow,2=all)

   b. `--slowms` (value of slow for profile and console log)

This will log only those slow calls that take more than specified slowms threshold for execution